# SaltStack NO onchange functionality

Tags: salt-stack

I trying to find a way how to execute a specific state only if the previous one completed successfully but ONLY when is without changes, basically, I need something like no onchanges.

```
start-event-{{ minion }}:
  salt.function:
    - name: event.send
    - tgt: {{ minion }}
    - arg:
      - 'PATCHING-STARTED'

start-patching-{{ minion }}:
  salt.state:
    - tgt: {{ minion }}
    - require:
      - bits-{{ minion }}
    - sls:
      - patching.uptodate

finish-event-{{ minion }}:
  salt.function:
    - name: event.send
    - tgt: {{ minion }}
    - arg:
      - 'PATCHING-FINISHED'
```

or in other words, I want to send ever "finish-event-{{ minion }}" only when "start-patching-{{ minion }}" is like:

```
----------
          ID: start-patching-LKA3
    Function: salt.state
      Result: True
     Comment: States ran successfully. No changes made to LKA3.
     Started: 11:29:15.906124
    Duration: 20879.248 ms
     Changes:
----------
```

Comment: I think this will need a [feature request](https://github.com/saltstack/salt/issues/new?assignees=&labels=Feature%2C+needs-triage&template=feature_request.md&title=%5BFEATURE+REQUEST%5D+"unchanged"+requisite)